# Getting custom beer crates in the US?

Tags: bottling, packaging

I'm about to embark on my first journey to home brewed beer, but as a German, there is one critical ingredient that makes a beer a beer: A Beer Crate, or Bierkasten as we call it:

[image: Beer Crate]

However, I have not seen them in the USA yet (Living in Orange County, CA), it seems that cardboard holders are the preferred way, which is kinda lame :)

I found a company to make custom crown caps, but so far I've been unsuccessful finding a company to make those plastic (HDPE) crates with a custom print, for 12 oz bottles. I found a company in China that can make me a batch of 2000, but that's massive overkill, I need 4 or 5 :)

Does anyone have any leads?

Comment: Not specifically meant for beer, but milk crates are readily available. These guys will even put your logo on it for you. http://www.buymilkcrates.com/

Comment: I feel like this would be more appropriate for a discussion in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), but we really don't have enough people sticking around there for it to be as useful as it could be.

Answer (score 2):

I would contact this company.  http://www.cwcrate.com/

They may be able to do custom printing on the crates or you could at least add one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What about a folding crate, like this one?

http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200485109_200485109

(Credit to http://www.homebrewfinds.com for originally providing me with the lead on this.)